# Applescript - Return songname when artist is printed before

Tags: applescript

I am trying to make a Applescript for use with BTT touchbar. 
The idea is to print the current playing artist - songname. When artist+song is longer then 20 characters I want to display first the artist and when the script runs again, display the songname, script runs again display artist, display songname... etc.

The script I use atm is only printing the artist.

Could anyone help me with fixing the script? Thank you!

```applescript
if application "Spotify" is running then
tell application "Spotify"
    if player state is playing then

        -- Gets the text of the current track playing 
        set _artist to get artist of current track
        set _name to get name of current track
        set _full_string to _artist & " - " & _name
        set _length to length of _full_string

        -- Gets the duration of the track that is playing 

        if (_name = "") or (_artist = "") or (_name = "Listen Now") then
            return "Ad"
        else
            if _length > 20 then
                return text of _artist #& "..." -- & _time          
                if text of result is _artist then
                    return text of _name
                else
                    return _full_string -- & " - " & _time
                end if

            end if
        end if
    else
        return ""
    end if
end tell
else
return ""
end if
```

Comment: Your problem is that you've nested one of your return values under the wrong `if...then...else` block.  You want to return the `_full_string` if its length doesn't exceed 20 characters, but currently there are no commands to execute in this instance as they're all under the case where its length *does* exceed 20 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of re-working your AppleScript a little.  It was all there, really.  You just had an over-abundance of `if...then...else` blocks that were making things confusing, and that's where you lost track of where your `return` clauses were going (one of them, anyway).

```
    property _artist : missing value
    property _name : missing value

    property show_artist : true


    tell application "Spotify"
        if it is not running then return ""
        if player state is not playing then return ""

        -- Gets the text of the current track playing 
        set [_artist, _name] to [artist, name] of current track
        set _full_string to [_artist, " - ", _name] as text

        -- No track or artist name or a value of "Listen Now"
        -- probably means an advertisement is playing
        if (_name = "") or (_artist = "") or ¬
            (_name = "Listen Now") then ¬
            return "Ad"

        -- Can return the full string if 20 or fewer characters
        if (length of _full_string) < 21 then ¬
            return _full_string

        -- Otherwise, have to split up the artist and track name
        -- and alternate between which one is returned with each
        -- script execution (using the show_artist flag)
        if show_artist then
            set show_artist to not show_artist

            if (length of _artist) < 21 then return _artist
            return text 1 thru 17 of _artist & "..."
        else -- show_artist is false
            set show_artist to not show_artist

            if (length of _name) < 21 then return _name
            return text 1 thru 17 of _name & "..."
        end if

    end tell

    -- This part of the script will never be reached
    -- so this superfluous return clause is just acting
    -- as a safety net.  Delete it if you like.
    return ""
```

Notice that I've only used one `if...then...else` statement, which makes it a little bit more efficient and easier to read.  I managed this by considering which conditions will cause the script to exit early, keeping in mind that it means that the rest of the script won't get executed.  So a single `if...then...return` line will do in those cases, and I attend to those first.

The only other thing I did was add in the ability for the script to keep track of whether the artist or the track name was returned in the previous run of the script (and hence to return the other one this time round).

This is achieved using the `property` declaration for `show_artist` (a boolean value), which I simply negate before returning either the artist or track name.  As property values are remembered between script runs (and only reset if you recompile the script), it'll continually alternate between `true` and `false`, which determines which of the two variables gets returned.

Try it out.  Paste it into *Script Editor* with a song playing (whose combined text length exceeds 20 characters), and keep hitting Cmd+R to execute the script.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't get my code block to use syntax highlighting.  I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: The script is working beautifully! Thank you for the extensive explanation, it is all more clear now. Another question; is it possible to always remain with 20 characters in the print, even when there are less characters to print? I ask this because now, if the complete name (artist+song) is longer than 20 characters, artist is 20 characters and the songname is 6 characters. When the songname is showing in my touchbar the size of the button will decrease. Thank you CJK!

Comment: You're very welcome, @TimvanderHoorn.  Feel free to +1 my answer and mark is as correct.  It'll help others and give me some brownie points.  If you want a text string to be a fixed length of 20 characters, even if the original string is shorter, then you could pad the end of the string with whitespace, e.g. `"Letters & spaces    "` has 20 characters, the latter 4 of which are spaces.  To ensure the button on your touchbar doesn't change size, however, requires the font used to print the artist and track is a monospaced font.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following working for me. Give it a go:

```
if application "Spotify" is running then
    tell application "Spotify"
        if player state is playing then
            return (get artist of current track) & " - " & (get name of current track)
        else
            return ""
        end if
    end tell
end if
if application "Music" is running then
    tell application "Music"
        if player state is playing then
            return (get artist of current track) & " - " & (get name of current track)
        else
            return ""
        end if
    end tell
end if
return ""
```